# How to call an oracle procedure on Laravel?

Tags: php, oracle, laravel, stored-procedures, laravel-5

I have an oracle database with Laravel and Yajra package, how can i call an oracle procedure from Laravel 5.4

This is my oracle procedure:

```
create or replace procedure PRW_GENERA_FACTURA(
            pnro in number, 
            pmsj out VARCHAR2
            ) is
        BEGIN
            pmsj := 'El nro. es '||pnro;

        end PRW_GENERA_FACTURA;
```

And i tried this on my Controller:

```
 $val1 = 20; 
 $result = DB::connection('ora_db')->select('exec 
 PRW_GENERA_FACTURA(?)',array($val1));
 return $result;
```

it gave me this error:

> Error Code : 900
>       Error Message : ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
>       Position : 0
>       Statement : exec PRW_GENERA_FACTURA(:p0)
>       Bindings : [20]
>       (SQL: exec PRW_GENERA_FACTURA(20))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have to do this in RAW format:

```
$val1 = 20; 

$result = DB::connection('ora_db')->select(
    DB::raw("exec PRW_GENERA_FACTURA(:val1)"), array ('val1' => $val1)
);

return $result;
```

this using php into the controller:

```
$conn = oci_connect('apxjfdev01', 'x....' ,'x...'); 
if (!$conn) { 
 $e = oci_error(); trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), 
 E_USER_ERROR); 
} 
$sql = ' BEGIN PRW_GENERA_FACTURA( :PNRO, :PMSJ ); END; '; $sql = 
oci_parse($conn,$sql); oci_bind_by_name($sql, ":PNRO", $val1, 32); 
oci_bind_by_name($sql, ":PMSJ", $val2, 32); 
$val1 = $id_f; 
oci_execute($sql);
```

Comment: give me an error:  Error Code : 900
Error Message : ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
Position : 0
Statement : exec PRW_GENERA_FACTURA(:val1)
Bindings : [20]
(SQL: exec PRW_GENERA_FACTURA(:val1))

Comment: Can you try `DB::raw("exec PRW_GENERA_FACTURA(" . $val1 . "))` to be sure that it has nothing to do with the statement. And can you try the same Statment in Oracle CLI (sqlplus)?

Comment: gave me the same error, but i fix it using raw php on my controller.. thanks for your help

Comment: $conn = oci_connect('apxjfdev01', 'x....' ,'x...');
        if (!$conn) {
            $e = oci_error();
            trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
        }


        $sql = '
        BEGIN
          PRW_GENERA_FACTURA(
            :PNRO,
            :PMSJ
          ); 
        END;
        ';
        $sql = oci_parse($conn,$sql);
        oci_bind_by_name($sql, ":PNRO", $val1, 32);
        oci_bind_by_name($sql, ":PMSJ", $val2, 32);
        $val1 = $id_f;
        oci_execute($sql);

Comment: OK this is a solution completely bypassing Laravel