# how to call a procedure in oracle to Laravel model

Tags: php, sql, laravel, oracle

I'm new to this, I have some project that I must use a procedure in my oracle to run on laravel model/controller, but first in the model I already had a query like this
Here the model I create

```
public static function updateskki($unitCode,$yearCode){
return DB::update("update PLNDEV.SKKI A SET (a.NO_PROGRAM,
a.DESKRIPSI_PROGRAM,
a.NO_ACTIVITAS,

...

WHERE A.UNIT_cODE=?
AND A.VERSION='Final'
and A.YEAR=?
and a.no_prk is not null 
and a.no_prk <> '-'
and exists (select 1 from PLNDEV.lkai d where d.no_prk=a.no_prk and
d.year=a.year and d.version=a.version)", [$unitCode,$yearCode]);}
```

here the procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "UPDATE_SKKI_REV"(pYEAR varchar2
default '2019',pUNIT varchar2 default 'PPDL')
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE SKKI A
SET (a.NO_PROGRAM,
a.DESKRIPSI_PROGRAM,
a.NO_ACTIVITAS,
...
WHERE A.UNIT_cODE=?
AND A.VERSION='Final'
and A.YEAR=?
and a.no_prk is not null 
and a.no_prk <> '-'
and exists (select 1 from lkai d where d.no_prk=a.no_prk and
d.year=a.year and d.version=a.version);
END;
```

I expected that I can call that procedure to change the model I create before,

I'm absolutely didn't know how to call it, It will help me if you can give me a reference or some examples with two parameters.
Thank you for read my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call an oracle procedure on Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593064/how-to-call-an-oracle-procedure-on-laravel)

Comment: not really a duplicate, I'm already look that question. and that didn't help me, already tried it. and his/her question didn't have parameters in their model.

Comment: You can change question marks with your received paramters. I'll post full code in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "UPDATE_SKKI_REV"(pYEAR varchar2
default '2019',pUNIT varchar2 default 'PPDL')
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE SKKI A
SET (a.NO_PROGRAM,
a.DESKRIPSI_PROGRAM,
a.NO_ACTIVITAS,
...
WHERE A.UNIT_cODE=pUNIT
AND A.VERSION='Final'
and A.YEAR=pYEAR
and a.no_prk is not null 
and a.no_prk <> '-'
and exists (select 1 from lkai d where d.no_prk=a.no_prk and
d.year=a.year and d.version=a.version);
END;
```

And you can call this procedure like this:

```php
DB::select("exec UPDATE_SKKI_REV(:year, :unit)", array ('year' => 1997, 'unit' => 'yourunit'))
```